# what does /%22%23%23%23/%22 mean in connection string path

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

I am new to this and I was wondering if anyone knows what the /%22%23%23%23/%22 in the connection string means for

```
connectionString = Data Source=(LocalDB)[file://SQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=/%22%23%23%23/%22;Integrated]\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\###\;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;
```

What is all the %22 and %23 mean here?

Comment: `%xx` is usually a url-encoded value. If you url-decode `/%22%23%23%23/%22`, you get `/"###/"`

Comment: *But* connection strings aren't URLs, they don't use such characters. Where did this come from?

Comment: `AttachDbFilename` contains a path to a database file. Obfviously, that's not a valid path. The connection string containst the same invalid string twise, in URL-encoded and plain form, ie : `AttachDbFilename=/%22%23%23%23/%22;Integrated]\\MSSQLLocalDB;` and `AttachDbFilename=\###\`. Did someone try to create a placeholder for a database file perhaps? And got the replacement string wrong?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Many connection strings such as PSQL and Mongo DB require to be URL encoded in some cases, so it would not come as a surprise to me if many database connectors can (and do) encode/ decode connection strings

Comment: Is the database attached to a server?  Then yo udo not need the AttchDbFile name nor the SQLLocalDb.  The filemae if local should have a mdf extension.

Comment: @MindSwipe that's not the case here, and the *content* is just invalid. The field is named `AttachDbFilename`. Both the encoded and decoded strings are invalid.

Comment: The *entire* `[file://SQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=/%22%23%23%23/%22;Integrated]` string is wrong. It looks like some code tried to insert another string into the original connection string?